# Flutter: How to scroll a list inside of Wrap widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using wrap to display some images, the direction of `Wrap` is set to `Axis.horizontal`. When it runs out of horizontal space, it is creating new row. As long as there is enough space vertically, everything is getting displayed as it should. But the moment there are a lot of images, it is giving a Bottom Overflow.

I tried wrapping the `Wrap` widget inside `SingleChildScrollView`, `ListView` and `Expanded` but nothing seems to work. Here is my code:

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Wrap(
      direction: Axis.horizontal,
      spacing: 8,
      runSpacing: 12,
      children: [
        _buildImageCard('abc'),
        _buildImageCard('def'),
        _buildImageCard('ghi'),
        _buildImageCard('jkl'),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

and the `_buildImageCard`

```dart
Widget _buildImageCard(String imagePath) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: 500,
      height: 400,
      child: Card(
        elevation: 5,
      ),
    );
  }
```

The result is:

[image]

Answer (score 19):

try **SingleChildScrollView**

```
  SingleChildScrollView(
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    child: Wrap(
      direction: Axis.horizontal,
      spacing: 8,
      runSpacing: 12,
      children: [
        _buildImageCard('abc'),
        _buildImageCard('def'),
        _buildImageCard('ghi'),
        _buildImageCard('jkl'),
        _buildImageCard('jkl'),
        _buildImageCard('jkl'),
        _buildImageCard('jkl'),
      ],
    ),
  );
```

[image]

Comment: As I want to scroll vertically, I set the scroll direction of `SingleChildScrollView` to `Axis.vertical` but it doesn't work. It works if I set it horizontally but I want to scroll vertically.

Comment: My code is same as yours but it isn't working for me, I am still getting bottom overflow.

Comment: mmmmm ok ,, your _buildImageCard is very big change it ,, example       width:150,
height: 200,

Comment: Even with small height and width, I am getting the same result.

Comment: try this       width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.3,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.3 ,

Comment: It didn't work. I finally managed to make it work by wrapping an upper column with SingleChildScrollView and it finally scrolled.

Comment: Optionally, insert an `Align` or `Center` between `SingleChildScrollView` and `Wrap` to have the scrolling area take up the full width.

Comment: SingleChildScrollView requires the contstraints in which it will scroll, so this won't work. 

Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67312368/14203110

Answer (score 10):

I met the same problem and I can solve it. The problem is `SingleChildScrollView` **requires** the contstraints in which it will scroll. So you need to specify them:

```dart
SizedBox(
  height: 100.0,
  child: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Wrap(
      children: [
      ],
    ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 2):

@bambinoua is right. You need to have constraints for `SingleChildScrollView` to work. So for example having infinity constraint for height won't work for vertical `SingleChildScrollView`. You can check the constraints being passed to it using `LayoutBuilder`:

```
LayoutBuilder(
    builder: (context, constraints){
        print('Constraints for SingleChildScrollView : $constraints');
        return SingleChildScrollView(...);
    },
)
```

If it's something like `BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=720, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)` then you need to inspect your widget tree to find the parent causing this. In my case it was a column and I solved it by wrapping the `SingleChildScrollView` in an `Expanded` widget:

```
Column(
    children: [
        ...
        Expanded(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(...)
        )
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 2):

for horizontal scrolling try this.

```
 Row(
  children: [
    Expanded(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            child: Wrap(direction: Axis.horizontal,
            children: [
              // childs here
            ],)))
  ],
);
```

[image]